# Is there a way to get Google Apps domain shared contacts to automatically show up in Google's contact manager?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-contacts

I'm trying to get all of my domain users to show up in Google Contacts automatically, but Google doesn't seem to support this basic feature. I could probably cobble something together with the [Profiles](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/profiles/developers_guide_protocol.html) and [Shared Contacts API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/shared_contacts/gdata_shared_contacts_api_reference.html), but is there any other way to do this? I know this this already pseudo-implemented with address autocomplete, but some of my users really want to have a list of domain contacts. I wouldn't care if it was an Apps Marketplace app or something that I had to park on a server and run. I'm running Apps Education Edition.

Answer (score 1):

Try SherpaTools for Google Apps  http://www.sherpatools.com/tour/ We are using it for a long time and is the best way to do all the contact / shared directory tasks using Google Apps. Even they have a 'robot' for Gtalk who replys with data from the Shared Conctacs List.

Answer (score 0):

I tested several free apps for sharing contacts, and this the best one I found so far. [Netkiller Shared Contacts](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=2333%205834727858349999229) is free, easy to use and [open source](https://code.google.com/p/netkiller-shared-contacts-for-google-apps/).